# Public and private keys in Google Cloud and WinSCP

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp, google-cloud-platform, private-key

I'm trying to transfer a directory of files from my local Windows 10 machine to the remote machine in Google Cloud. I'm following [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files?authuser=1#transfergcloud) tutorial to connect WinSCP to the GCP.

But in step 7 I have to specify the path of my private key file and I do not really understand where it's supposed to come from (does it the key that generated earlier with keygen-tool in the remote machine?)
[image]

I tried to generate a new key with PuTTYgen but it did not help.

[image]

What should I do to connect my local computer to the remote server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have some confusion about the private key.

Follow the [WinSCP guide for Connecting to Google Compute Engine server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine). In short:

- Use [PuTTYgen tool](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) to [generate new key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen#generating).
- Enter your GCE username to *Key comment* box.
- Copy a contents of *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file* to the clipboard (note that the contents includes your username);
- Go to *Metadata* page of your project on Google Cloud Platform;
- Go to *SSH Keys* tab;
- Add your key and save.